# Hiding or Removing Main Div Group Toolbar in VSCode: Seeking Assistance

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

How can I hide or remove the toolbar or row displaying the main div groups in my file within VSCode? I'm uncertain of the exact terminology, but I've attached an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: `sticky scroll`

Comment: Great, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the feature of Breadcrumbs if you want to disable Breadcrumbs in Visual Studio Code,
you can do so by updating your settings. Follow these steps:

Click on the gear icon in the bottom left corner to open the Settings.
In the Settings menu, click on "Settings"
Now, In the search bar at the top, type "breadcrumbs". and then uncheck the "Enable/Disable navigation Breadcrumbs" option.[image: Here is the screenshot of how you can do so]

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding. I wanted to disable the element located beneath the breadcrumbs, specifically the one marked with lines (2, 45, 53, 54, 55).